# Where to save state of npm command line tool?

Tags: node.js, directory, npm, save

I'm making a global npm command line tool, and I'm looking to save and write certain user configured settings that can persist between runs in a `.json` somewhere.

Currently, I'm simply writing them into the same folder as the package but I'm not sure if there might be any problems with permissions when doing so. Are there any good practices that I can follow to select a directory to save these settings for both unix and windows machines universally?

Comment: You should probably create the `.json` file in the user's `home` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular approach is to save your config the the user home directory. For example `mytool` utility creates `.mytoolrc`-file in the `~/` user folder.